# Understanding proof that smooth morphism is flat ( Gortz's Algebraic geometry, Theorem 14.22 )

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, proof of Theorem 14.22 and stuck at some statement.

> Theorem 14.22. Let $f: X \to Y$ be a smooth morphism of schemes. Then $f$ is flat.

Here the 'smoothness' is defined as

[image]

*Proof ( of Theorem 14.22 ) .* Since flatness can be checked locally, it is enough to prove the assertion for a smooth morphism in "standard form" : Let $R$ be  a ring, and $f_1, \dots, f_{n-d} \in R[T_1, \dots,T_n]$ be polynomials such that for all $x\in \operatorname{Spec}R[T_1, \dots , T_n]/(f_1,\dots, f_{n-d})$, the Jacobian matrix $J_{f_1, \dots, f_{n-d}}(x)$ has rank $n-d$.

We will prove by induction on $i$ that

$$ R[T_1, \dots, T_n]/(f_1 ,\dots , f_i) = (R[T_1, \dots ,T_n]/(f_1, \dots, f_{i-1}) )/ (f_i)$$

is flat over $R$. Using Lemma 14.21

[image]

, it is enough to show that for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subset R$, $f_i$ is regular ( ;i.e., non-zero divisor ) in $A_{i-1} := (R/\mathfrak{m})[T_1, \dots, T_n]/(f_1, \dots, f_{i-1})$.  But by induction hypothesis $\operatorname{Spec}A_{i-1}$ is smooth over the field $R/\mathfrak{m}$ ( I think that I checked this fact and for now we accept this statement ), so by Lemma 6.26 all localizations of $A_{i-1}$ in prime ideals are regular and in particular integral domains.

[image]

Thus $A_{i-1}$ is a product of domains. In fact, by the proof of the Eisenbued, Commutative Algebra, Proposition 2.20., $A_{i-1} \cong \prod_{1 \le j \le l} A_{i-1}/Q_{j}$, where $Q_1, \dots ,Q_l$ are (finitely many) minimal primes of $A_{i-1}$.  So $\operatorname{Spec}A_{i-1} \cong \operatorname{Spec}(A_{i-1}/Q_1) \uplus \cdots \uplus \operatorname{Spec}(A_{i-1}/Q_l) \cong V(Q_1) \uplus \cdots \uplus V(Q_l) $ ( irreducible components ).

**And all its irreducible components have dimension  $n-i+1$.** Since analogously the dimension of $A_i$ is $n-i$. **it follows that $f_i$ cannot vanish on any irreducible component of $A_{i-1}$, and hence is a regular element of $A_{i-1}$.**

Q. Why the bold statements are true?

**Q.1.** Why the first bold statement is true? Perhaps, $\operatorname{Spec}A_{i-1}$ is equidimensional of dimension $n-i+1$? $A_{i-1}$ is Cohen-Macaulay ring?  ( Then $\operatorname{Spec}A_{i-1}$ is Cohen-Macaulay (?) so it is equidimensional ( Gortz's Proposition 14.124. ) )

**Q.2.** Why the second bold statement is true? What the sentence "$f_i$ cannot vanish on any irreducible component of $A_{i-1}$" exactly means ? And why from this $f_{i}$ is regular element of $A_{i-1}$?

Note that $ \dim V(f_i) =\dim A_{i-1}/(f_i) =: \dim A_i = n-i \le n-i+1 = \dim A_{i-1}$. From this can we show that $f_{i}$ is regular element of $A_{i-1}$ ?

Can anyone help ?

Comment: 1) don’t you know that “smooth of relative dimension $d$ over some field” implies “equidimensional of dimension $d$”?

Comment: 2) the spectrum of $A_i$ is the subscheme of the spectrum of $A_{i-1}$ made of the points “at which” $f_i$ vanishes. If $f_i$ vanished on an irreducible component $Z$ of the spectrum of $A_{i-1}$, then the spectrum of $A_i$ would contain $Z$, which has dimension $n-i+1$ by Q1. But the spectrum of $A_i$ ha dimension $n-i$, so that’s impossible. In particular, the image of $f_i$ in every $A_{i-1}/Q_j$ is nonzero hence regular. Since $A_{i-1}$ is the product of these rings, the conclusion follows.

Comment: Thank you dear Aphelli ! Perhaps, where can we find associated proof for the equidimensionality of smooth morphism of relative dimension d over a field?  In the Liu'z Algebraic Geometry book, that is true by part of definition 4.3.35. Or in the Vakil's note it is by 12.6.4 Theorem. But the definition of smoothness of relativd dimenzion n in the vakil's note ( 12.6.2 definition ) seems slightly different with ours. ~ (Are they equivalent ?)

Comment: Your definition is almost certainly equivalent to Vakil’s (by the standard Nakayama argument of “true in a residue field -> true in a ring of stalk -> true in an open neighborhood” and by the right choice of variables). To show that “smooth over a field” implies equidimensional, my guess is to see that locally at closed points, the sequence of the $f_i$ can be completed to a basis of the cotangent space. This implies that the stalk of your smooth scheme is regular of the correct dimension.

Comment: Yes. Thank you~